# mysql select using combined columns

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where I need to search a database for an employee using the end-user submitted name

currently my database is set up

```
ID | Username | Fname |  Lname  | Passw
1  | JHStaffo | James | Stafford| Hash
2  |  GSmith  | George|  Smith  | Hash
```

the user entered in "James Stafford" for the input - splitting is not an option unless absolutely mandatory. I need the database to resolve to select ID 1 only

I attempted

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE fname + " " + lname = "James Stafford"
```

However this selects ALL rows even if the where does not appear to match - What is the proper syntax for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did u mean

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE concat(fname," ",lname) = "James Stafford"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE CONCAT(`fname`, ' ', `lname`) = 'James Stafford'
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem should be easily solved by using `CONCAT` and `LIKE` string function.

```
SELECT * FROM users where CONCAT(fname, " ", lname) LIKE "James Stafford"
```